# How I can interpret the correct date in Javascript when the year is of the format yy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have defined an input that accepts only dates in HTML.
The user can enter the date manually or by using a Calendar which is defined in javascript.
I am using Javascript  and Jquery to convert the input to a date:

```
var lStartDateText = $j("#DateStarte").val();
var lEndDateText = $j("#DateEnd").val();
var lEffStartDate = new Date(lStartDateText);
var lEffEndDate = new Date(lEndDateText);
```

My problem is that when the user enters the following date manually 1/1/50 is interpreted as 1/1/1950 but 1/1/49 is interpreted as 1/1/2049. I want it always to be interpreted as 20xx.

On the other hand the Calendar allows the user to choose a year from 2006 to 2021 in case the user wants to choose a date from it and not enter it manually.

Hope I can get some help here ??

Comment: Java is not Javascript, you do know that, right?

Comment: This is a joke ??? .

Comment: Have you considered using Moment.js: http://momentjs.com/ ?
I provides many ways to format your date objects.

Comment: @Abadi what is a joke?

Comment: It would be better if I don't introduce new librabries.

Comment: try to use validation with a message or put place holder dd/mm/yyyy to denote the user

Comment: The user can choose two type of date format either of the form "yy" or "yyyy".

Comment: @abadi please check my example. its working "yy" and "yyyy" both format

Answer (score 0):

If you know your getting the last 2 digits of the year (`50`), and you know you always want to add the first 2 digits, which are constant (`20`), that's a slight modification to your code:

```
var lStartDateText = '20' + $j("#DateStarte").val();
var lEndDateText = '20' + $j("#DateEnd").val();
```

Note that this is not particularly robust, e.g. if the user enters text which is not a date you might end up with a string like `'20hi'`, but that may be outside the scope of your question and it will be parsed as an invalid date.

```js
$('#year').on('change keyup', function() {
  var y = $('#year').val();
  if (y.length === 2) {
    y = '20' + y
  }
  if (y.length === 4) {
    var dateY = new Date();
    dateY.setFullYear(y);
    $('#result').html(dateY);
  } else {
    $('#result').html('No YY or YYYY date found');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="year">Enter year (YY or YYYY)</label>
<input id="year" type="text">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I validate the date that is entered by the user.I will ahve only to check if the date  is being entered by the user in the form of "yy" and not "yyyy"

Comment: @Abadi See my example for a fairly complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lStartDateText = $j("#DateStarte").val();
var lEndDateText = $j("#DateEnd").val();

var lEffStartDate = ReFormatDate(lStartDateText);
var lEffEndDate = ReFormatDate(lEndDateText);

function ReFormatDate(dateString) {
    var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
    if (dateParts[2].length === 2) {
        dateParts[2] = "20" + dateParts[2];
    }
    return new Date(dateParts.join("/"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```js
var lStartDateText = "1/1/50" ;
var lEndDateText = "1/1/49" ;
var res = lStartDateText.slice(4);
var starttext = lStartDateText.replace(res,"20"+res);
var res1 = lEndDateText.slice(4);
var endtext = lEndDateText.replace(res1,"20"+res1);
alert(starttext);
alert(endtext);
var lEffStartDate = new Date(starttext);
alert("start date"+lEffStartDate);
var lEffEndDate = new Date(endtext);
alert("End Date"+lEffEndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it's will be help you.

```js
 $('#year').on('change keyup', function() {
   var right_date = $('#year').val();
     var data = $('#year').val().split('/');
  if (data[2].length == 2){
   var twoDigitsCurrentYear = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(0,2));
   $('#result').html(data[0]+'/'+data[1]+'/'+twoDigitsCurrentYear + data[2]);
  } 
     else {
     $('#result').html(right_date);
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="year">Enter year (YY or YYYY)</label>
<input id="year" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yy">
<div id="result"></div>
```